# The equivalent of websvn for Git

Tags: git, interface, websvn

Am currently using **websvn** in my server to visualize svn branches.

Since i've recently introduced Git, i'm looking for an equivalent to graphically see git

Answer (score 1):

Type **`gitk`** in your git bash, its a build in GUI tool for Git.

[image]

---

The better option is to install [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/)

[image]

Comment: On Windows, Git Extensions provide great native GUI.

Comment: Sourctree much much of a better choice

Comment: I'd refrain from expressing personal opinions, really -- they are unfit for SO. I understand the OP's desire to find a tool that suits their needs but let's be up to the point and merely suggest what's available and let the OP do their own evaluation. That would be way more in line with the SO's guidelines.

Comment: Those options are only for desktop. Is there anything for web, just like websvn?